# Is it possible to hide specific Desktop-icons with C#?

Tags: c#, desktop, icons, show-hide

I'm searching for a way to hide specific Icons from the Desktop. I usually have way to much icons on my desktop (which makes finding a file a real hassle), so I would like to write a little tool, which "filters" them as I type. I do not want to "move" or delete them, just hide (or darken) them. I know how to toggle show an hide-status of all icons at once, but not on a per icon basis. Any ideas?

Comment: If you make this app, send it to me please :)

Comment: Sure - no problem, I would open source it anyways :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'd try to somehow navigate to the desktop's `ListView` control (using Win32 API). Then I'd either draw some semi-transparent rectangles over the items I want to hide (you can query the rectangles of items using the `ListItem_GetItemRect` macro/message), remove items temporaryly from the list control, set the status of the items to `CUT` (which fades the out) or I'd try manipulate the list view's image list to add a transparent image and set the item's images to this.

But I have no idea if this approach would work ... And I'm not sure if I'd try this in C# (I'd rather use C++).

Comment: I really like the rectangle idea! I will try this as well. I think I will stay in .Net, my Win32 C++ experience is almost zero.

Answer (score 3):

@crono, I think wich your best option is add a reference to the COM library "Microsoft Shell Control And Automation" and use the [Shell32.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094%28VS.85%29.aspx) object. and then enumerate the shortcuts and set the file atributes (FileAttributes.Hidden) of the shortcuts.

check these links for more info.

- [FolderItem Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787810%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [ShellLinkObject Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774004%28VS.85%29.aspx)

see this simple example, is not complete, is just a draft.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using Shell32; //"Microsoft Shell Control And Automation"

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Shell32.Shell oShell;
                Shell32.Folder oFldr;
                oShell = new Shell32.Shell();
                oFldr = oShell.NameSpace(Shell32.ShellSpecialFolderConstants.ssfDESKTOP);//point to the desktop

                foreach ( Shell32.FolderItem oFItm in oFldr.Items()) //get the shotrcuts
                {

                    if (oFItm.IsLink)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ", oFItm.Name, oFItm.Path);

                        bool isArchive = ((File.GetAttributes(oFItm.Path) & FileAttributes.Archive) == FileAttributes.Archive);
                        //bool isHidden = ((File.GetAttributes(oFItm.Path) & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden);

                        if (isArchive) //Warning, here you must define the condition for hide the shortcut. in this case only check if has set the Archive atribute. 
                        {

                            //Now you can set  FileAttributes.Hidden atribute
                            //File.SetAttributes(oFItm.Path, File.GetAttributes(oFItm.Path) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ", oFItm.Name, oFItm.Path);
                    }

                }

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but I think it would only work, if I set "display hidden files" to "false" - which I have "on" most of the time. Maybe I could change it "on the fly"... I will hav a look. Thanks :)